# Dance of spider mountain hammer combo

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Would mountain hammer work standing on a stone wall in dance of the spider stance? Would the attack bypass hardness and give bonus damage to cut through bars on a window?

Comment: I came here hoping that "the Dance of Spider Mountain" was a thing. I imagine it would involve much swiping at air and batting at clothing.

Comment: Gratuitous "can't touch this/MC Hammer" reference inserted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paragraph describing Stone Dragon maneuvers, there's this information:

> Unlike with other disciplines, adepts of this school rely on an external force—the power of the earth and stone—to help power their maneuvers. As a result, Stone Dragon maneuvers can be initiated only if you are in contact with the ground. (*Tome of Battle* 81)

While a creature is in the Shadow Hand stance dance of the spider, the creature is still climbing. According to the stance

> you gain a benefit similar to the *spider climb* spell (*PH* 283). You gain a climb speed of 20 feet. You do not need to make a Climb check to traverse a vertical or horizontal surface, even if you attempt to move across a ceiling. You retain your Dexterity bonus to AC while climbing, and you must have at least one hand free to support yourself while you climb. (*Tome of Battle* 76)

Neither the skill [Climb](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/climb.htm), the spell [*spider climb*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiderClimb.htm), or the description of the [climb speed movement mode](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#climb) mention that because a creature can traverse vertical surfaces more easily that this somehow changes what *ground* is for the creature.

So, unfortunately, the ground is that thing you hit when climbing goes wrong, *not* the horizontal surface you're currently occupying when doing climbing right.<sup>1</sup>

Thus, absolutely, the maneuver mountain hammer can break bars on a window. Given enough time, an adept who's readied the maneuver mountain hammer can probably break most of the *dungeon*. He just can't, according to the rules, do so while climbing.

**Note:** That *only if you are in contact with the ground* tidbit is easily missed and never mentioned anywhere else ever again. This DM encourages nearly any reasonable house rule that lets martial characters have more fun, and the Stone Dragon maneuver mountain hammer (*ToB* 84), given its accessibility and utility, is certainly one of those ways. A house rule excising that limitation is, certainly, reasonable.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *false gravity* [trans] (*SpC* 87-8) comes *really* close to the affected creature being able to switch what counts as *ground*. If really worried because the DM won't house rule away the Stone Dragon discipline's limitation, see if the DM will let that spell do the job then purchase potions or a wand.

Comment: 1) also, unless you're climbing a cliff. It's still ground, right? Or is it this a nuance that English language has?

Comment: @Zachiel There are a half-dozen different English definitions of *ground*, but a quick search of SRD for *ground* makes it pretty clear the game means *ground* as in *not walls* (and, for that matter, *not cliffs*) (e.g. "snow on the ground," "perpendicular to the ground," the [dwarf trait stability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dwarf.htm)--this last perhaps the clearest example). Could it've been even clearer? Absolutely.

Comment: Then again, the fluff says you need to touch the ground because you take power from earth and stone. While you probably have RAW, I guess RAI is ...hinted at at least.

Comment: @Zachiel I wish I knew what the real intent was. Was it to nerf otherwise easily accessible maneuvers? To mandate a specific playstyle? Merely to add flavor to the discipline? Whatever that real intent, I'm almost certain it wasn't to mildly inconvenience the Stone Dragon adept by forcing him to put rock in his shoe and then say to the DM, "Now I'm *always* in contact with the ground."

Comment: I think, there are ways around this limitation. For example, securing a rope around yourself and letting it touch the ground (your boots count, the rope should too) - or using a spell akin to Tongue Tendrils from BoVD to have a part of YOURSELF (your tongue) touching the ground. If it's not too high, even giving yourself a +5-10 reach should do the trick - it's really up to the player's creativity, like many things in the game 8)

Comment: @Baka-Mastermind It's really the wizard's spellbook problem in another venue: if the DM exploits a PC's vulnerability, the DM's a dick; if the DM never exploits a PC's vulnerability, it's not a vulnerability. Except while we *know* the wizard's spellbook is supposed to be a vulnerability, this almost trivial *contact with the ground* thing seems so offhand and last minute that it's kind of hard to tell if it's supposed to *be* a vulnerability.

Comment: I'd call it a good sport for the player to both FOLLOW this particular vulnerability and find his way AROUND it. Even if DM is totally okay with letting it slide, making your own character invent a way to negate this "gotta touch the ground" requirement will surely give additional flavor to the roleplaying aspect of the game